# Best method for filling in faces in complex/irregular area

Tags: faces

What would be the best method for filling in faces in a complex area, like a key (see image below)?

Does Blender have a tool for handling situations like this quickly?  Or is there a few ideal tactics for handling a situation like this?

[image]

The solution I settled on is shown below below?  It looks to work fine with the subdivision modifier.  Are there things in this solution that should have been avoided?

[image]

Comment: you can select all these vertices and extrude inwards, actually your topology is not very good but if you don't see any artifacts in Render mode, you don't care

Comment: Extruding them inward was what I attempted in the first picture.  It didn't seem the way to go because the vertices would pile up on each other on the right and it didn't seem like they would mesh well with what was available to connect to on the left.  Is there an example somewhere you could direct me to to see how to go about making good topology.

Comment: maybe show a picture of the original object if you have one, is it a key?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your topology is a bit messy and you don't need as many vertices, but is it really important? You should not have any artifacts because I suppose it's going to stay a flat surface, you could even use huge ngons. Also don't hesitate to use tris on the round corners:

[image]

But here is a try with a bit simpler topology:

[image]

or even:

[image]